# How to add autocomplete from jquery-ui to Rails 5 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to implement jquery-ui's autocomplete, but seems like I'm missing something very important.
I'm following these guide from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised) (also available on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA)). But I'm using Rails 5.1 and respectively `yarn` instead of the gem.

Also I'd like to mention that I already have `datepicker` and `tabs` implemented and working well.

Here is `package.json`'s dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
"rails-ujs": "^5.2.0",
"turbolinks": "^5.1.1"
 },
```

So in the top of my `application.js` I have this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widget
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs
```

And in the bottom:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#high_edu_name").autocomplete({
    source: $('#high_edu_name').data('autocomplete-source')});
});
```

I receive the following error on the page load:

```
TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).menu is not a function
```

from `autocomplete.js:215:15`

And when I try typing something to the text field I get:

```
TypeError: keyCode is undefined
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that error suggests jquery ui not loaded correctly. Are you using webpack?

Comment: no, i'm using vanilla jquery-ui, and yes, you're right - I wrote below where I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well, lack of docs about installation through yarn is embarassing...

I made it through - it takes explicitly defining:

```
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu
//= require jquery-ui/ui/keycode
//= require jquery-ui/ui/position
//= require jquery-ui/ui/version
```

The result looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widget
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu
//= require jquery-ui/ui/keycode
//= require jquery-ui/ui/position
//= require jquery-ui/ui/version
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs
```